How to select a value from each sql row to use in a function and then update each row
I need to update each row in a table with a value returned by a function. This function uses a separate columns value of the same row. I understand how to select a columns value from a row and how to update one but not how to do both for every row in a table.
For example if I had a table with employees information like their birthdate, how would I use python to take that birthdate, run it through a function to determine their age and then update that specific row's age column with that determined age. I know how to do this for one row, but not for every row in the table that does not yet have a value for their age.
cursor = connection.cursor()


for row in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table' WHERE Birthdate != ''):
   sql_update_query = """Update name-of-table set age = %s where 
   age = '' """
   age = CurrentYear - yearBorn
   input = (age)
   cursor.execute(sql_update_query, input)

Sorry for the sloppy code but here is an example of what I have tried to do ^


Indentation in Python matters.  2) You declare cursor2 but never use it.


I changed it to only use one cursor but forgot to change the part where I was using two. Also I fixed the indentations. Not sure if this is something allowed or if I need two cursors?

The UPDATE query is updating all rows with an empty age, not just a row related to the current row of the cursor. You need to restrict it to a specific row, usually by using the primary key in the WHERE clause.

Don't use input as a variable, you're overwriting the input() function. And you need a comma to make it a tuple: (age,)

Is name-of-table in the UPDATE the same as Table in the SELECT?

Yes, they are the same table

You need to make the update specific to the current row of the loop. Use the primary key of the table for this -- I've assumed it's called id in my code below.
sql_update_query = """Update employees set age = %s where id = %s"""

for id, birthdate in cursor.execute('SELECT id, BirthDate FROM employees' WHERE Birthdate != ''):
   age = calculate_age(birthdate)
   cursor.execute(sql_update_query, (age, id))


cursor = connection.cursor()

current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year

query = "UPDATE your_table SET age = {} - (YEAR(birthdate) + IF(MONTH(birthdate) > MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), 1, 0)) WHERE age = ''"
cursor.execute(query.format(current_year))

